# TruncatedSVD returning incorrect dimensions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a matrix which I am trying to decompose to lower dimensions using the `TruncatedSVD` class in sklearn. For the `n_components` argument in the constructor, I am passing 500. But when I check the shape of the dataframe returned by the `fit_transform` method, the number of columns are not equal to 500. I am not sure whats causing this. Here's the code-

```
# ORIGINAL DATAFRAME
tfidf_df.shape #(277, 51023)

# INITIALIZE SVD DECOMPOSER
svd_decomposer = TruncatedSVD(n_components=500, # Desired dimensionality of output data
 algorithm='randomized', # SVD solver to use
 n_iter=5, # Number of iterations for randomized SVD solver
 random_state=42, #  pseudo-random number generator
 tol=0.0 # Tolerance for ARPACK
 )
svd_decomposer.n_components #500

# DECOMPOSE THE DATAFRAME
tfidf_svd = svd_decomposer.fit_transform(tfidf_df)
tfidf_svd.shape # (277, 277)
```

Shouldn't the output dataframe `tfidf_svd` be of shape `(277, 500)`. I cant figure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be expected behaviour. The `TruncatedSVD` function calls the `randomized_svd` function and inside that there's the following code:

```
if transpose == 'auto':
    transpose = n_samples < n_features
if transpose:
    # this implementation is a bit faster with smaller shape[1]
    M = M.T
```

So the maximum number of components you will be able to return is the number of samples you have. I can't remember exactly why, but I'm pretty sure there's a linear algebra explanation as to why you're limited to the number of samples that you save. You see the same behaviour in both implementations of SVD in scikit.

**EDIT**

The reason why is (stolen from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28909/pca-when-the-dimensionality-is-greater-than-the-number-of-samples)):

If `n` is the number of points and `p` is the number of dimensions and `n≤p` then the number of principal components with non-zero variance cannot exceed `n` (when doing PCA on raw data) or `n-1` (when doing PCA on centered data - as usual)